# Issue with lazy loading Framework Entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity, lazy-loading

I am using Entity with lazy loading and I have to following problem,
I'm running a query that doesn't include related properties but when I try to serialize the object, serializer is trying to load the related properties and since my context is disposed I'm getting an exception.

What I want to do is set all related properties to null when they are not loaded (some times I might include them in my query and I'd like them to be serialized in that case).
Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. I use Json.Net for serialization, and set LazyLoadingEnabled = false.

```
using (var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    var list = dbContext.Videos.Take(5).ToList();

    var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
}
```

Comment: AsNoTraking() does not prevent proxy creation and lazy loading.

Comment: what serializer use?